# Calling data from API in editor after saving it, the data shows up, when I refresh the page it says data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

[image: here is image of data in console log]

I have problem rendering data on page, it's fetching nicely when I type code and save it renders, but after refreshing page it says data undefined. specifically `data.name`. Here is code and you can see it in console too:

```
const CryptoDetails = () => {
  const { coinId } = useParams()
  const [timePeriod, setTimePeriod] = useState('7d')
  const {data, isFetching } = useGetCryptoDetailsQuery(coinId)
  const cryptoDetails = data?.data?.coin
  
  //console.log(data);

  return (
    <Col className='coin-detail-container'>
      <Col className='coin-heading-container'>
        <Title level={2} className='coin-name'>
          {cryptoDetails.name} ({cryptoDetails.slug}) Price //problem is this name!!
        </Title>
```

`const cryptoDetails = data?.data?.coin;` (calling it and working)
after returning `{cryptoDetails.name}`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Any suggestions?

Comment: would you please change `{cryptoDetails.name}` to `{cryptoDetails?.name}` and then try. thanks

Comment: No worries, I will be happy to help you again. :)